# Find b that (a+b) divisible to K

Tags: python, algorithm, number-theory

I have integer input: `0 < a, K, N < 10^9`
I need to find all b numbers that satisfy:

- a + b <= N
- (a + b) % K = 0

For example:  10 6 40 -> [2, 8, 14, 20, 26]

I tried a simple brute force and failed (Time Limit Exceeded). Can anyone suggest answer? Thanks

```
a, K, N = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
count = 0
b = 1

while (a + b <= N):
    if ((a + b) % K) == 0:
        count+=1
        print(b, end=" ")
    b+=1

if (count == 0):
    print(-1)
```

Comment: You should share your code from your brute force attempt.

Comment: _"I tried brute force and failed"_. How exactly did it fail?

Comment: Do you really need all of the b's, rather than count them? There can easily be a billion b's, listing them (no matter how) would take a significantly amount of time.

Comment: I've never seen `Time Limit Exceeded` thrown before

Comment: this is simple math and doesn't need brute forcing at all

Comment: A hint: all of those `b`s differ by a multiple of `K` (in your example: 8 = 2 + 6, 14 = 8 + 6 etc). So you only need to find the minimal `b`.

Comment: Hint: if you only want the count of the `b`s, you can calculate it with some division.

Comment: @bereal nice method bro, but is still gives TLE when i submit my code

Comment: @NguyễnPhúcSơn code, please.

Comment: Thanks for this. I miss really simple number theory problems. I'm afraid I've forgotten most of the fundamentals by now.

Comment: You're missing the point entirely.  The kinds of sites that pose these problems select them because the obvious brute-force solution isn't sufficient.  You're supposed to use your own knowledge and problem-solving skills to come up with an alternate solution.  Asking the internet for help is cheating.

Comment: Of course you got a TLE, the contest is designed to do exactly that. The idea of these contexts is that *you* invent a clever algorithm. Writing down an algorithm in any programming language is not a challenge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first condition is trivial in the sense that it just poses an upper limit on `b`. The second condition can be rephrased using the definition of `%` as

```
a + b = P * K
```

For some arbitrary integer `P`. From this, is simple to compute the smallest `b` by finding the smallest `P` that gives you a positive result for `P * K - a`. In other words

```
P * K - a >= 0
P * K >= a
P >= a / K
P = ceil(a / K)
```

So you have

```
b0 = ceil(a / K) * K - a
b = range(b0, N + 1, K)
```

`range` is a generator, so it won't compute the values up front. You can force that by doing `list(b)`.

At the same time, if you only need the count of elements, `range` objects will do the math on the limits and step size for you conveniently, all without computing the actual values, so you can just do `len(b)`.

Comment: For `a=2`, `K=5` `P` should be 3, but your formula returns 1. I think, the better way would be `P=K - a%K`.

Comment: @bereal `(2 + 3) % 5 == 0`. That's with `P == 1`. Seems fine to me...

Comment: Ah, I misread the part of the equation, sorry. I meant that minimal `b` can be found as `b0 = K - a%K`.

Comment: @bereal. Your solution is more elegant and doesn't require importing `math` so I'll add it momentarily, once I've convinced myself that is correct.

Comment: @bereal. Here's a counter example: `K = 3, a = 12`. Your formula gives `b0 = 3`, when it should be 0. Unless `b > 0`, in which case you're absolutely right and my answer is actually incorrect.

Comment: Yeah, `K` being an `a`'s divisor is a special case, in which `b=0` is the only answer. Depends on what the original puzzle expects to receive for this. If they want to see `0`, the formula can be generalized as `b0 = (K - a%K) % K`.

Answer (score 0):

To find the list of `b`s, you can use some maths. First, we note that `(a + b) % K` is equivalent to `a % K + b % K`. Also when `n % K` is 0, that means that `n` is a multiple of `K`. So the smallest value of `b` is `n * K - a` for the smallest value of `n` where this calculation is still positive. Once you find that value, you can simply add `K` repeatedly to find all other values of `b`.

Answer (score 0):

```
b = k - a%k
```

Example: `a=19`, `k=11`, `b = 11-19%11 = 11-8 =3`